# Pattern Regex Java two patterns at the same time?

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to sort some text using regex pattern, and i already have something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w{4,30}\\b");
```

If i'm right it should give me strings of 4 to 30 characters long, but i don't want any number in my Strings too, don't know how to make two filters at the same time, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to allow digits in your matches, just do not want to get any digit-only matches? `"\\b(?!\\d+\\b)\\w{4,30}\\b"`? Or `"\\b[^\\W\\d]{4,30}\\b"` to avoid any digits in your expected matches?

Comment: Do you mean like `\b[a-zA-Z_]{4,30}\b`

Comment: Or something like `^([^0-9]{4,30})\b` ? Please show us some of the text and the desired output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank You! the first option work best for me!
Please if You can tell, why so many \\b right there? or try to explain for me this line of code:
 "\\b(?!\\d+\\b)\\w{4,30}\\b"

Comment: @Theo for example the input is: 
"Superalloys
1992
Warr
endale"

And as Output i wanned to be something like this: 
"Superalloys
Warr
endale"
But the answer of Wiktor work's great :)

Comment: Ah, **replace** all digits. I thought you wanted to get only strings that have no digits in them. I think it is best if @WiktorStribiżew writes his working comment as answer (maybe include the regex details) so you can accept that.

Comment: See the answer below with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
"\\b(?!\\d+\\b)\\w{4,30}\\b"
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hFjrKs/1). The main things here are [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) and the negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) construct that restricts the chars the word to be matched should consist of.

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\d+\b)` - no 1 or more digits immediately to the right of the current location is allowed up to the end of the word
- `\w{4,30}` - 3 to 30 word (letter, digit or `_`) chars
- `\b` - a word boundary.